# Automate layer comment insertion for animations?

Tags: gimp, animation

I am reading this tutorial on how to create GIF animations in GIMP.

https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/

The tutorial says,

> In GIMP you specify the delay as a layer comment. Just double-click
>   the layer comment in the layers’ window and a delay in ms enclosed in
>   brackets ().

I have several hundred frames. Is there a way to add this text procedurally versus typing the comments all in by hand? Thanks.

Comment: You can change the delay when you export a GIF, no need to do them one by one.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I only want most of the frames to have the same delay. Some need to be different.

Comment: Is it hundreds of frames that need to be different, or just a few?  The GIF export dialog allows you to change frame delays that are unspecified, so it won't change those you have already specified.

Comment: That's nice, but I'm really more interested in an  answer to my question.

Comment: I'm asking you a question to help clarify your question. Is it hundreds of frames that need to be different, or just a few?

Comment: In my current animation, just a few.

Comment: So here's a plan. Just change the few frame delays that you need, by specifying them manually. Then when you export the GIF, set the frame delay for the unspecified ones (i.e the hundreds of other frames).

Comment: Like I said, this is a nice workaround for the time being, but it still doesn't answer my question. I may need something more powerful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [retime-linked-layers-0.0.py](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). Should be self-explanatory. Remember that you can mass-change the "link" status of layers by shift-clicking the chain icon.